# Edit many-to-many relationship in Flask-SQLAlchemy withg WTForms

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I struggle handling a many-to-many relationship (here: users and groups) in a Flask form. My database structure (simplified) looks as follow:

```
association_user_group = db.Table(
    'association_user_group',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
)

class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'group'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    users = db.relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=association_user_group,
        backref=db.backref('groups', lazy='dynamic'))

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    @property
    def group_ids(self):
        return [u.id for u in self.groups]
```

To handle a form that allows an admin to edit the users, I have:

```
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()

class UserEditForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password')
    groups = MultiCheckboxField('Groups', coerce=int)
    submit = SubmitField('Apply changes')
```

and the following route:

```
@bp.route('/user_edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@admin_required
def user_edit(id):
    user = User.query.get(id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UserEditForm(obj=user)
        form.groups.data = [grp.id for grp in user.groups]
    else:
        form = UserEditForm(request.form)
    form.groups.choices = [(grp.id, grp.name) for grp in Group.query.all()]

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #form.populate_obj(user) <-- does not work
        user.username = form.data.username
        if form.password.data != '':
            user.set_password(form.password.data)
        # how do I update the 'groups'?
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return "Data={}".format(form.data)
```

The database and form works, but I am unable to copy the `groups` form content back to the database. Ideally, I'd be able to 'populate back' the form content to the `User` object, but this fails because of the `groups` (and I think it might also fail with the password field that is empty if no change is requested).

I then tried to delete all `groups` from `user` and re-add the ones I want, but did not figure out a reasonable way to achieve this. I am able to add an group membership with `user.groups.append(grp)` where `grp` is the corresponding database object. I also am able to `remove` a group membership in the same way, but given the group ids this would mean looping through all group ids, retrieving the group object, and then using this object to invoke the `remove` method, which seems overly complicated.

Overall, I suspect that I attempt to implements all this in a far too awkward way...